# Writing a PySpark dataframe to Snowflake from Databricks takes a very long time

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

```
df.write.format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake").options(**sfOptions).option("dbtable", "table_name").mode("overwrite").save()
```

I'm using the above code in Azure Databricks to write a Spark table to Snowflake db, and it took 7+ minutes to complete for just 9mil+ rows.

I am using a single node cluster with Node type Standard_D64s_v3 (256GB, 64cores), and installed Maven package "net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.5.1-spark_2.4".

Is there some setting I am missing in order to reach it's full speed?

Comment: Or is 7minutes considered fast? I asked ChatGPT and it estimates that it should take 1-2hrs to write a 10mil rows table to Snowflake.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest checking if `sfOptions` has option `"usestagingtable": "ON"` activated.

---

[Internal Data Transfer](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-overview#internal-data-transfer)

> The transfer of data between the two systems is facilitated through a Snowflake internal stage that the connector automatically creates and manages:
>
> - Upon connecting to Snowflake and initializing a session in Snowflake, the connector creates the internal stage.
> - Throughout the duration of the Snowflake session, the connector uses the stage to store data while transferring it to its destination.
> - At the end of the Snowflake session, the connector drops the stage, thereby removing all the temporary data in the stage.
>
> Note that support for internal transfer requires a specific version (or higher) of the connector, based on the cloud platform for your Snowflake account:
>
> - AWS     The internal data transfer mode is supported only in version 2.2.0 (and higher) of the connector.
> - Azure   The internal data transfer mode is supported only in version 2.4.0 (and higher) of the connector.
> - GCP     The internal data transfer mode is supported only in version 2.7.0 (and higher) of the connector.

---

[Additional Options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#additional-options)

> usestagingtable
>
> This parameter controls whether data loading uses a staging table.
>
> A staging table is a normal table (with a temporary name) that is created by the connector; if the data loading operation is successful, the original target table is dropped and the staging table is renamed to the original target table’s name. If the data loading operation fails, the staging table is dropped and the target table is left with the data that it had immediately prior to the operation. Thus the staging table allows the original target table data to be retained if the operation fails. For safety, Snowflake strongly recommends using a staging table in most circumstances.
>
> In order for the connector to create a staging table, the user executing the COPY via the Spark connector must have sufficient privileges to create a table. Direct loading (i.e. loading without using a staging table) is useful if the user does not have permission to create a table.

Comment: I now turned it on, but it still took 7.9minutes to write to Snowflake.

Comment: @EeAnnNg Could you share more details like query history for this load/query profile, virtual warehouse setup?

Comment: This data was read from Snowflake as a PySpark dataframe, converted to Spark.Pandas dataframe and some manipulation was done on it, and then converted back to PySpark dataframe and then written to Snowflake. The Snowflake warehouse is a Medium sized one, I don't have much info on the Warehouse as I am not the admin, could you let me know exactly what setup info you're looking for so that I can ask my admin for the info?